# Excel formula stops working midway through data sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have created a nested `IF then` statement (Excel 2010) to compare two columns to report out either true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative, or default error.  The statement is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(I535="NEG",N535="NEG"),"TN",IF(AND(I535="NEG",N535="POS "),"FP",IF(AND(I535="POS ",N535="NEG"),"FN",IF(AND(I535="POS ",N535="POS "),"TP","ERR"))))
```

This statement has worked wonderfully in all previous data sets and works for the first 500 rows in this new data set.  However, at ~500 rows into the data set the if then statement stops working and reports out either a `TN` or `ERR` (formula was expanded by dragging corner down to fill rows).  I have tried to manually set to an array with no success.  I have also used the replace function to confirm that every `POS` and `NEG` is formatted correctly (no extra spaces etc.)  I have also tried moving parts of the data to a new file with no luck.  To make things even more frustrating there are two rows # 922 and 1166 that report out correctly.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space after POS. e.g."POS "

Try this instead:

```
=IF(AND(I535="NEG",N535="NEG"),"TN",IF(AND(I535="NEG",N535="POS"),"FP",IF(AND(I535="POS",N535="NEG"),"FN",IF(AND(I535="POS",N535="POS"),"TP","ERR"))))
```

Also a simpler way to do this might be to have a vlookup table somewhere as such:

```
NEGNEG TN
NEGPOS FP
POSNEG FN
POSPOS TP
```

Then you can just do a vlookup of Concatenate(I535,N535)